# Importing Active Directory Users and Groups into SQL Server (possibly via c#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, active-directory

I need to import all ad groups in a few OUs into a table in SQL Server 2008.  Once I have those I need to import all the members of those groups to a different table.  I can use c# to do the work and pass the data to SQL server or do it directly in SQL server.

Suggestions on the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arry,

I don't know exactly, but found some links that may help you. I think the hottest track is this expression:

```
"(&(objectCategory=Person)(memberOf=DN=GroupName, OU=Org, DC=domain,
DC=com))"
```

I found it in [LDAP Query for group members](http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:55298) on a ColdFusion community's site. I'm more or less sure the filter can easily be applied to your query. I'm sorry, but I cannot test it, because I have no AD around here.

This one could also be a bit (but less) interesting:

http://forge.novell.com/pipermail/cldap-dev/2004-April/000042.html

Hope this helps, cheers,

Matthias

Comment: The filter described in this answer is the best way to return all users within an Active Directory Security Group that I have found.

Answer (score 8):

Add a Linked Server to your SQL Server and query the Active Directory via LDAP queries. This here described this quite well:

[Create a SQL Server View of your AD Users, Brendan Tompkins (MVP)](http://codebetter.com/blogs/brendan.tompkins/archive/2003/12/19/4746.aspx)

Comment: I think you can only return 1000 active directory objects from within SQL server, because you can't do a paged query from SQL server.

Answer (score 2):

As the OP of this question seemed open to other technologies (3 years ago), I posted a walk through that uses SSIS as the technology for querying AD for users, writing those users to a table and doing group lookups on those users.  [Active Directory SSIS Data Source](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/04/active-directory-ssis-data-source.html)  Even if you aren't interested in SSIS, the LDAP query for source objects and the C# for group membership might be handy for anyone reviewing this question.